# Reverse proxy in location nginx

Tags: nginx, wso2

I have a 404 error when access to location

`HTTP Status 404 - /wso2/`

My nginx configuration is this. If i use only / in location all works fine, but i need use the same domain for cross domain reasons.

```
upstream mywso2 {
        server localhost:9443;
    ip_hash;
}

server {
        server_name myidp.io;
        location ^~ /wso2/ {
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
               proxy_read_timeout 5m;
               proxy_send_timeout 5m;
               proxy_pass https://mywso2;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

When i access to myidp.io/wso2 i have a 404 error

Comment: What's `https://mywso2` supposed to mean? It's not a qualified domain, of course there's nothing to be found there

Comment: Is reference to upstream in top on my code

Comment: could you try to change "localhost" with 127.0.0.1 ? Then why use ip_hash if you have a single localhost upstream?

Comment: The upstream request becomes `https://mywso2/wso2/`, so the upstream server is probably generating the 404 status because it was expecting `https://mywso2/`. You could try `proxy_pass https://mywso2/;` (with the trailing `/`)

Answer (score 0):

`ip_hash` config is not needed if this is a single-node setup.

Try `location /wso2 {` and change the proxy pass to `https://mywso2/;`.